# Only allow answers to be added after 5 minutes or so

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is a serious issue. SO users are becoming more and more competitive. I don't mind that, but, here is what is happening.

1. I start reading the question
2. I see `"1 new answer to this question button"`
3. The answer is a one-liner
4. The answerer edits it multiple times to make it a *proper* post which is useful to OP.
5. I'm left wondering "Why on earth does this happen to me?"
6. I'm left with no other option to leave a comment: `"+1 you beat me to it!"`
7. Search for another question to answer in the hope of the above not getting repeated :(

The issue is serious. Answering first has its own advantages. Some time should be there to read the question completely and then post an appropriate answer, which is helpful to OP.

What if my internet connection is slow? And many times, when I try to answer first, this nasty reCaptcha comes and asks me some hell as if I'm a robot. I don't blame them though. But in the time of *answering* reCaptcha, other users have already posted their answers.

### My Suggestion:

So, I propose to add timeout the same way as one cannot accept an answer in 10 minutes.

The submit button shall remain disabled for 5 minutes<sup>+</sup> and after that, it can be answered. This will make sure that all get equal time to understand and answer the question correctly.

<sup>+</sup><sub>Note the time limit can be set according to general consensus.</sub>

Comment: duplicate: [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't an answering competition. Adding features to level the competitive playing field is silly, since the whole problem is that you choose to treat it as a competition.

Comment: The "problem" of people quickly answering questions is as old as Stack Overflow itself. It's one that doesn't really need a solution.

Comment: I find it rather amusing that you also answer posts 1 minute after the question is asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23389513/should-i-declare-i-in-for-loops/23389556#23389556

Answer (score 11):

I like Wooble's comment, "Stack Overflow isn't an answering competition."  It is a Q/A site for information.

Many User questions can be answered in a one-liner, in a minute or less.  When people graciously donate their time to help others through Stack Overflow, they may be able to provide such an answer.  There is no reason to make the people who answer questions wait an arbitrary period of time—it would interfere with their ability to use the site.  They may not be patient for 5 minutes, and may just leave.  Furthermore, the "speed competition" for answering questions is only moved 5 minutes later, not eliminated.  And in the vast majority of cases, the viewers of the question provide valuable feedback on the answers in the first 5 minutes which would not occur if the feature change you proposed is implemented.